# Was The 4400 based loosely on Scientology?

Tags: religion, the-4400

I just finished watching the 4400 up to its last season before its cancellation. I couldn’t help but notice its overtones to what seemed to match L Ron Hubbard’s Church of Scientology religion.

Were there any out-of-universe comments from the directors/producers/writers about alignment with or borrowing of parts of Scientology beliefs for the storyline or overall plot for the show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At last I have my answer. I cornered 4400 co-creator Scott Peters at the Warner Bros. party at Comic-Con and asked him what he thought of my theory. He laughed and said with exaggerated understatement, "Oh yeah, it's about that just a little bit. The Scientologists never came after us, though."
>
> <sub><sup>[Yes, "The 4400" Was Partly About Scientology](https://io9.gizmodo.com/yes-the-4400-was-partly-about-scientology-5324023)</sup></sub>

Comment: If anything the church probably appreciated the free and dramatic PR.